# Woocommerce: How to reorder single page hooks?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce-based site and now I'm on the single page. My doubt is how to reorder some hooks there. Originally, we have this order (priority):

```
<?php 
/*
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
  * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
*/
?>
```

According to my layout, I need to put the elements on this exactly order:

```
1: Title
2: Name of the product category (last level category where that product was classified in the admin)
3: Quantity switch and "add to cart" button
4 and last: Description
```

How can I redefine this on my "functions" file in my theme? Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

This was so long ago but in case anyone is interested, in functions.php file remove and add your own action to reorder contents of single product summary:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40);
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert description into Summary:

-> **replace XX with the proper priority number**

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_product_description_tab', XX ,1)
```

Comment: Not sure this really answers the original question, the question is "how to reorder single page hooks", your answer is to insert the description. I also tested the code and it doesn't do as the OP asks.